# About the problem after setting Function.__proto__.__proto__ as null

Tags: javascript, prototype

At first, I want to verify all reference types in js has __proto__ attribute is because all reference types is Object.

So to verify this I set the Function.__proto__.__proto__ as null to see whether the __proto__ of Function will disappear.

After doing operatins above, the Function.__proto__ is undefined but it is strange that when I show Function in console, the [[Prototype]] attribute is still there and is the same as the value of prototype attribute.

```
Function.__proto__.__proto__ = null;
console.dir(Function.__proto__) //undefined
console.dir(Function) // can still see [[Prototype]] on console
```

Comment: If you want the `__proto__` of `Function` to disappear, why don't you just do `Function.__proto__ = null`? Why do you set `Function.prototype.__proto__ = null`?

Comment: "*I want to verify all reference types in js has `__proto__` attribute is because all reference types is Object.*" - no they don't. Not all objects inherit `__proto__` from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: "*the [[Prototype]] attribute is still there*" - why would you expect it to be gone?

Comment: Please do not use `__proto__` for anything, it is deprecated and useless. Always use `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`!

Comment: About 'Not all objects inherit __proto__ from Object.prototype' , If there is any example that an Object dose not have __proto__?

Comment: About 'why don't you just do Function.\_\_proto\_\_ = null? Why do you set Function.prototype.\_\_proto\_\_ = null' , I want to prove that after the root Object.prootype is set null, all \_\_proto\_\_ of the objects in the prototype chain will be affected

Comment: About ' Not all objects inherit \_\_proto\_\_ from Object.prototype ' , if there is any counter expample? I saw on one atricle that claims all data in js is object.

Comment: About 'why would you expect it to be gone', I found that Function.__proto__ is undefined, but why it is still shown in console, it is contradictory.

Comment: "*I saw on one article that claims all data in js is object.*" - everything is an object, but not everything is an `instanceof Object`. There's things from other realms, there's things like `Object.create(null)`, there's `Object.prototype` itself.

Comment: "*I found that `Function.__proto__` is undefined, but why [[prototype]] is still shown in console, it is contradictory?*" - no, these are two separate things. An object always has a prototype chain (internal *[[prototype]]*), which can be another object or `null`. But you can't remove it. `__proto__` is just a boring getter that some objects inherit and others don't. As I said, better forget about it.